# Quand met-on un adverbe avant le « pas » dans une phrase négative?

Tags: grammaire, négation, adverbes

Quand met-on un adverbe avant le « pas » dans une phrase négative?
Dans beaucoup d'articles sur l'emplacement des adverbes, j'ai lu que l'adverbe, généralement, est mis après le « pas » dans les phrases négatives

> Il ne m'a pas seulement parlé

; mais j'ai vu beaucoup de phrases comme ceci:

> Il ne sais simplement pas

L'adverbe est mis *avant* le « pas », et non après. Pourquoi est-ce ainsi?
J'ai vu aussi:

> Ce n'est donc pas

Est-ce ainsi parce que ce sont des exceptions?

Comment: *Quand un adverbe précède le verbe, pas se place généralement avant l’adverbe, sauf
lorsqu’il s’agit des adverbes* certainement, généralement, peut-être, probablement, sans
doute: http://www.ccdmd.qc.ca/media/allo_adv_005Allophones.pdf (page 3)

Answer (score 2):

Dans une succession de deux adverbes, le premier modifie le second ; quand l'un des deux est un adverbe de négation (pas, plus, guère, ...) l'ordre peut donc changer le sens des phrases.

Ce n'est pas sûrement lui = peut-être que c'est lui, peut-être que ce n'est pas lui -- on ne sait pas, on n'en est pas sûr

Ce n'est sûrement pas lui = ce n'est pas lui, on le sait, on en est sûr.

Answer (score 1):

C'est très simple et ce n'est pas particulier au français.

Quand l'adverbe est avant, il qualifie le "*pas*". Il renforce, atténue ou nuance la négation :

> Vraiment pas
>
> Probablement pas

Quand l'adverbe est après, le "*pas*" apporte la négation à l'adverbe, pour exprimer son contraire :

> Pas vraiment
>
> Pas complètement

En anglais on a la même chose avec *Not really / really not* par exemple.

Et "*donc*" n'est pas un adverbe, c'est une conjonction de coordination.